# jQuery modal dialog opens multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog

Can you please help me to understand why does my javascript function open modal popup multiple times? so if I click on the link for the first time modal appears, then I close it and open again - if I want to close it I should press Cancel two times etc.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

      $('.modal-class').click(function () {
          $("#modal-popup").load(this.href, function () {
              var target = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-popup")
              $(target).dialog({
                  autoOpen: true,
                  closeOnEscape: true,
                  width: 400,
                  resizable: false,
                  title: 'Login Form',
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                      Login: function() {
                      // perform login
                $.post("@Url.Action("Login", "User")",
                {
                    username: $('#Email').val(),
                    password: $('#Password').val()
                },
                function() {
                        $('.modal-popup').dialog("close");
                        $('#main').load("@Url.Action("Index", "User")",
                        {
                            uniqueName: $('#Email').val()
                        });
                });
            },
                      Cancel: function () {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                      }
                  }
              });
          })
          return false;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize model only one time. You are doing it whenever the click event is triggered. After the first initialization, execute the below line to open dialog each time.

```
$(target).dialog("open");
```

Also, You should set the option 'autoOpen' to false. Otherwise modal will be open when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the modal already opens on click without your javascript code (part of a framework)? Do you have a sample of the html code too?
Try adding `e.PreventDefault()` on the first line of this javascript code, see what happens.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely an event that fires twice. Alternatively, add a console.log('Fire!') and see how many times it is printed into your console. If it's more than once, that's where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a style='display:none' on the modal-popup div.  I'm pretty sure that's the attribute that the .dialog("open") operates on.